# How to insert a record in a gridview(repeater) at client side and sort the records after that (ASP.NET Web Forms)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to create a simple game in a CANVAS. So when the game is finished, the user is asked to fill his/her name. Also I have a GridView(Repeater) with all high scores stored in a database. I am using ASP.NET Web Forms and my purpose is, when the user fill his name and click certain button in the canvas, to update the table with the high score(Reordered by the score). Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: What did you try, can you show your code?

Comment: I am trying to use the <input type="text"..> generated dynamically with javascript and populate the result in the gridview with resorting by high score. I am working on the code so I will  add it later. Thanks, anyways